# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Example API threw exception on trying to return a JSON object using Jersey

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I get the following errors:

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Example API threw
>   exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet Example API threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Example API
>   threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.text.ParseException: Next
>   event is not a Token
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:289)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:274)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.addProduces(IntrospectionModeller.java:173)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutResourceMethodsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:303)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:126)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1595)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1356)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) root cause
>
> java.text.ParseException: Next event is not a Token
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextToken(HttpHeaderReader.java:102)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.QualitySourceMediaType.valueOf(QualitySourceMediaType.java:84)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$5.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:360)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader$5.create(HttpHeaderReader.java:358)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readList(HttpHeaderReader.java:481)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readList(HttpHeaderReader.java:473)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readAcceptableList(HttpHeaderReader.java:461)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readQualitySourceMediaType(HttpHeaderReader.java:365)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readQualitySourceMediaType(HttpHeaderReader.java:373)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:287)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.createQualitySourceMediaTypes(MediaTypes.java:274)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.addProduces(IntrospectionModeller.java:173)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.workOutResourceMethodsList(IntrospectionModeller.java:303)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:126)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1595)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1356)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) note The full stack trace of
>   the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.24 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.24

When I try to run the following the following program:

```
package com.example.api;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.json.JSONObject;

@XmlRootElement
class User
{
    String user;

    public User () {}

    public User (String user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUser ()
    {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser (String user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

@Path("/hello/{user}")
public class Sample {
    @GET
    @Produces("/application/json")
    public User getMessage(@PathParam("user") String user) {

        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(new User (user));
        return new User (user);
      //  System.out.println(j.toString());
       // return j.toString();
    }
}
```

Following is the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.api</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.mock</groupId>
    <artifactId>MockAPI</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

If I produce plain string, the program runs fine. Why can I return JSON objects here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Produces` annotation should be `@Produces("application/json")` just remove the `leading` slash.
You can also use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`